# WebView minimum zoom is too big and table shown inside is not resized correctly

Tags: java, android, html, webview, html-table

I defined a `WebView`(which is called timeTable) and called `loadDataWithBaseURL` like this:
`timeTable.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<html><head></head><body>" + str + "</body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8",null);`

Basically `str` is a String that contains a well-formed html table.
This is the table compiled in the computer:
[image]

In order to allow zoom I called:

`timeTable.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                    timeTable.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

When the `WebView` is loaded, this is what you see:
[image]

It is way too zoom in, and this is the most far zoom possible.
Also, as you can see, in the screenshot from my phone the top left side of the table is shown. If you look at the top left cell, for example, you can see that in the phone it is resized to be 10 unreadable lines, while in the computer it is 2 readable lines.

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

To set default zoom of your WebView, you can try to use:
`timeTable.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);`

You can find more information about Zoom density [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.ZoomDensity.html). 
Other way to provide initial zoom value is to use viewport metatag in your html code, for example:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Useful information about this tag and its usage can be foud [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/22/the-ie-mobile-viewport-on-windows-phone-7.aspx).

Comment: Is your webview only as big as your screen? Is it possible to scroll trough the table to see other cells or not?

Comment: Yes. it is possible to scroll and the webview is filling all the screen (except for the tabs)

Comment: Well, then last thing I can imagine is to specify device-width in viewport. You can try: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`. It should set the page to fit the width of your device screen.

Comment: nothing...
If there is a way that the cells will be resized the same as the computer screenshot ( 2 lines instead of 10) it will be okay.